# Create a horizontically stretched upper triangular matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, memory-efficient

I'd like to create a `4x12` matrix which is very similar to a upper triangle matrix, it looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

So my question is. What is the most efficient way to create it? no loops, no cellfun. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `vectorized` approach -

```
nrows = 4;
ncols = 12;

row_idx = repmat(1:nrows,ncols/nrows,1)
out = bsxfun(@le,[1:nrows]',row_idx(:).')
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an upper triangular matrix of ones, permute second and third dimensions, repeat along second dimension, and reshape into desired shape:

```
m = 4;
n = 12;
result = reshape(repmat(permute(triu(ones(m,m)), [1 3 2]), [1 n/m 1]), [m n]);
```

Comment: Nice job! `repelem` seems to be not only convenient, but also fast!

Answer (score 2):

The **Matlab R2015a and later** approach using the newly introduced [**`repelem`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
n = 4;
m = 3;
out = repelem(triu(ones(n)),1,m);
```

---

```
out =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

It even seems faster than the `bsxfun` approach, though I can't believe this ;)

---

### Benchmark

Unfortunately I couldn't consider **andrew's solution** as it is not complete and I didn't got it totally.

```
function [t] = bench()

   n = 4;
   m = 12;
   t = zeros(3,15);
   for ii = 1:15
        fcns = {
            @() thewaywewalk(ii*n,ii*m);
            @() Divakar(ii*n,ii*m);
            @() LuisMendo(ii*n,ii*m);
        };
        % timeit
        for jj = 1:100;
            t(:,ii) = t(:,ii) + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
        end
   end

   plot(1:15,t(1,:)); hold on;
   plot(1:15,t(2,:)); hold on;
   plot(1:15,t(3,:)); hold on;
   xlabel('Matrix size: n = x*4, m = x*12')
   ylabel('timing')
   legend({'thewaywewalk','Divakar','Luis Mendo'},'location','northwest')

end
function Z = thewaywewalk(n,m) 
    Z = repelem(triu(ones(n)),1,m/n);
end
function Z = Divakar(n,m)  
    row_idx = repmat(1:n,m/n,1);
    Z = bsxfun(@le,[1:n]',row_idx(:).');
end
function Z = LuisMendo(n,m)
    Z = reshape(repmat(permute(triu(ones(n,n)), [1 3 2]), [1 m/n 1]), [n m]);
end
```

[image]

### First bottomline - small matrices:

The new [**`repelem`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) does a very good job, but also the `reshape(repmat(permute...` does not disappoint. The `bsxfun` approach stays a little behind for some medium-sized matrices, before it becomes the leader for large matrices:

### Second bottomline - big matrices:

As predicted by Divakar, `bsxfun` is the fastest for larger matrices, actually as expected as `bsxfun` is always the fastest! Interesting that the other two align perfectly, on could guess they almost work the same internally.

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the datasizes a bit more, like `n = 40` & `m = 120`? Those plots would look much different then.

Comment: @Divakar the biggest used was `m = 15x12 = 180` for `n = 15x4 = 60` sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I saw that, but I still think those are small for a proper benchmarking.

Comment: @Divakar I will run the loop with ` for ii = 1:10:150`, let's see what the gives. I'm also surprised about the jump the graph does for bsxfun

Comment: Don't worry, the surprises would be gone :)

Comment: Well, now I can agree. I think there is a typo for the conclusions for the small matrices benchmarks.

Comment: By the way, awesome effort on the benchmarks. Appreciate it really. Thanks for the corrections too!

Comment: You're welcome, I was motivated by the possibility of beating bsxfun, but thats a pointless task...

Comment: I understand that! :) Also, on benchmarking, try to cover a wide range of datasizes, helps to really know which functions and techniques are slow, etc. those kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your matlab version

```
m = 4;
n = 12;

dec2bin(bitshift(num,-1*[0:n/m:n-1])) %this prints out a string
```

these should be logical arrays (i don't have either of these so I cant test it)

```
decimalToBinaryVector(bitshift(num,-1*[0:n/m:n-1]))

de2bi(bitshift(num,-1*[0:n/m:n-1]))
```